# need to merge rows into two colums mysql

Tags: mysql

please advice how to make SQL query in order to get from this table

```
ID|Number|Type|
----------------
1 |AA1   |IN  |
2 |AA2   |OUT |
3 |AA3   |IN  |
4 |AA4   |OUT |

into this result

ID|  IN  |  OUT |
-------------------
1 | AA1  |  AA2 |
2 | AA3  |  AA4 |

Thanks
```

Comment: What is the purpose of you getting output in such format ? If it is plainly for display purpose; my suggestion is to do this in your Application code. You can easily use arrays, for each loops etc, to get it in whatever format you want to display in

Comment: I thought about it if there is no any sql :)

Comment: I am trying to do this via MySQL as a challenge. Few queries: Is it safe to assume that there will always be a `IN` for every `OUT` ? Also, will `IN` and `OUT` be always consecutive, or they may have any order ? Can there be some `IN` values, with no corresponding `OUT` ?

Answer (score 2):

This Will work using Implicit join.

It will use mysql session variables. for reference, you can read http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-variables/ for session variables.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @row_number2 = 0;
SELECT
    out_table.OUTs AS outs, in_table.Ins as INs  FROM
  (SELECT
          (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS num2,  Number as OUTs FROM your_table WHERE  your_table.Type = 'OUT')   as out_table ,
       (SELECT
          (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num1,  Number as Ins FROM your_table WHERE  your_table.Type = 'IN')   as in_table
  WHERE num2 = num1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate row_number like functionality, using session variables. We get all INs and OUTs separately in two derived tables and do a `LEFT JOIN` on them, to get the desired output.

This will work even for the cases where `IN` and `OUT` are not consecutive. It will also handle the cases where there is an `IN` without `OUT`.

It would not work for the case when there is an `OUT` without `IN`.

Try the following query:

```
SET @row_no_1 = 0;
SET @row_no_2 = 0;

SELECT 
    t1.row_no AS ID, t1.Number AS `IN`, t2.Number AS `OUT`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @row_no_1:=@row_no_1 + 1 AS row_no, Number
    FROM
        `your_table`
    WHERE
        Type = 'IN'
    ORDER BY id ASC) AS t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        @row_no_2:=@row_no_2 + 1 AS row_no, Number
    FROM
        `your_table`
    WHERE
        Type = 'OUT'
    ORDER BY id ASC) AS t2 ON t2.row_no = t1.row_no
```

Answer (score 0):

answering myself...

```
SELECT a.ID
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = "IN" THEN a.Number ELSE "" END) AS IN_Type,
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.type = "IN" THEN b.Number ELSE "" END) AS Out_Type
FROM table1 a Left join table1 b on a.ID = b.ID
Group by a.ID
```